# Alarm Manager Doesn't stop play

Tags: android

I made an alarm clock and it's working almost great.
My problem is that alarm manager doesn't stop.

I have a toggle button to setup alarm but when i am pressing the off state, alarm manager doesn't stop play the ringtone.

Here is my code:

```
public void OnToggleClicked(View view){

    long time;
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()){
        Toast.makeText(activity_mainnew.this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getMinute());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmTimePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        time = (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time){
            if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
            else
                time = time + (1000*60*60*24);
            }
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10000, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();

            Toast.makeText(activity_mainnew.this, "ALARM OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Ιn my AlarmReceiver class i have:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonder why a **repeating** Alarm keeps repeating?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialise the pendingIntent,

```
    ...else
    {    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
         pendingIntent.cancel();
    }....
```